# DataFrame having case sensitive and not inserted in hive table

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, pyspark, bigdata

Facing one scenario where dataframe is having case sensitive and while inserting this dataframe into hive table it is throwing error as columns ambiguity

`E.g:daframe_test.columns[ABC, abc]`

Can we have both values from columns dynamically handled at runtime without throwing error

Tried with one solution by setting `spark.set.conf("spark.sql.caseSensitive", "true")`

But while inserting this dataframe into hive table after adding this property throws error/exception as memeory overhead and heap space etc issues. As well not want this property in real-time project to set up

Comment: I might be wrong, but the column names in Hive should not be case sensitive as Hive does not support it. Maybe you can change that in the hive-site.xml, but I doubt it

Answer (score 0):

Hive does not support case sensitive column names. You will have to rename the columns to ensure that they comply with the naming schemes in Hive.